# How to store csv file into webjob

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-webjobs

I have created a azure webjob with queue trigger with search parameters.
I want to process searching using these parameters and save records into a csv file.

I want a way to store csv file on azure, so that i can send download link for that to user?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the CSV using Azure Blob Storage. By ensuring the container has the correct permissions, you can then obtain the link directly to the blob and send to the user. In addition you can use SASUrls to limit the duration of URL validity.

Answer (score 0):

> I want a way to store csv file on azure, so that i can send download link for that to user?

You could generate csv file and write it to Azure blob storage, here is a simple sample, please refer to it.

```
public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("myqueue")] string message, [Blob("mycontainer/{queueTrigger}.csv")] out string output, TextWriter log)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("ID");
    dt.Columns.Add("Name");

    dt.Rows.Add("1", "fred");

    //your logic to query the result 
    //and generate CSV string

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    IEnumerable<string> columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                                        Select(column => column.ColumnName);
    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString());
        sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
    }


    output = sb.ToString();

    log.WriteLine(message);
}
```

After you store csv file in Azure blob, you could provide user with the URL of mycontainer/{blobname}.csv. And you could allow anonymous access or provide clients with a shared access signature (SAS) to make blob available to other users.

Please check "[Controlling access to blob data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs#managing-security-for-blobs)" section to know how to control access to blob data.